# Filtering ICollection

Tags: c#, icollection

This code doesn't work, but:

```
public virtual ICollection<SomeItem> items { get { return (ICollection<SomeItem>)items.Where(e => e.isVisible == true); } set { ;} }
```

I'd like to do something to that effect. So to get an ICollection filtered by a property of the collection's elements.

Sure, I could iterate through the elements, and get the right ones, put them in a new collection and return with that, but is there a nicer solution?

Comment: What error message do you get ?

Comment: Why it is not working? What `items` are?

Comment: You want to use a property in itself? That'll give you the famous `StackOverFlow` exception.

Comment: Where returns an `IEnumerable<SomeItem>`. The easiest way to get an implementation of `ICollection<SomeItem>` is calling [ToList()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261(v=vs.110).aspx), which returns a [`List<SomeItem>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx), which implements `ICollection<SomeItem>` (along with a handful other interfaces)

Comment: Did you add using System.Linq; at the top of the source file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps what you're looking for is an [**Extension Method**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx)?

> Extension methods enable you to "add" methods to existing types without creating a new derived type, recompiling, or otherwise modifying the original type.

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static ICollection<SomeItem> OnlyVisible(this ICollection<SomeItem) items) {
        return items.Where(e => e.isVisible).ToList();
    }
}
```

Note that `Where` returns an `IEnumerable`, which you cannot modify, so I call `ToList()` which essentially does everything in your last sentence.

You would then use it like this:

```
void Foo(ICollection<SomeItem> items) {

    foreach (var i in items.OnlyVisible()) {
        // Use i
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
items.Where(e => e.isVisible == true).ToList()
```